# Getting pixel color on screen and knowing when it changes. Pinball

Tags: automation, colors, screen, detection

I am using java to try to repeatedly hit alternating ramps on the Pinball FX3, the game fish tales. My strategy is to use a pixel that is normally green, when it changes to another color (silver), I can use a timer to wait to flip at the perfect time. The return is so consistent that once the value is dialed in, it will never miss and have no chance to fail. I am trying to use a pixel on the left inlane, but I don't think i'm getting the right pixel as it is never green.

```
package pinballReallyBadFishTales;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException, InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        
        
        while(1==1) {
            
            Robot r = new Robot();
            ArrayList<Color> c = new ArrayList<Color>();
            
            for(int i=0; i<1; i++) {
                for(int j=0; j<1; j++) {
                    System.out.println(r.getPixelColor(565+i, 521+j));
                    c.add(r.getPixelColor(611+i, 535+j));
                }
            }
            int counter = 0;
            for(int i=0; i<c.size(); i++) {
            if(isWithin(c.get(i).getRed(), c.get(i).getBlue(), 30)) {
                if(isWithin(c.get(i).getRed(), c.get(i).getGreen(), 30)) {
                    if(isWithin(c.get(i).getGreen(), c.get(i).getBlue(), 30)) {
                        counter++;
                    } 
                }
            }
            }
            //for(int i=0; i<c.size(); i++) {
                //Color temp = c.get(i);
                //if(temp.getGreen() > 200) {
                    //counter++;        
            //  }
        //  }
            
            
            if(counter > 20) {
                r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F);
                r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_J);
                Thread.sleep(300);
                r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F);
                r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_J);
                System.out.println("Shoot");
            }
            
                
            PointerInfo a = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
            Point b = a.getLocation();
            int x = (int) b.getX();
            int y = (int) b.getY();
            System.out.print(y + "jjjjjjjjj");
            System.out.println(x);
        }
            
        }
        
        
        
    
    
    public static boolean isWithin(int a, int b, int howMany) {
        if(a>b) {
            int difference = a-b;
            if(difference < howMany) {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            int difference = b-a;
            if(difference < howMany) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        PointerInfo a = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
        Point point = new Point(a.getLocation());
        SwingUtilities.convertPointFromScreen(point, e.getComponent());
        int x=(int) point.getX();
        int y=(int) point.getY();
        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println(y);
    }
        
}
```

I"ve tried moving around the point to see if it was off, it can correctly identify white when I'm on a page such as this, and black. But when I go in game I can't seem to get it to look at the right pixel.